# Escape pass in Python

Tags: python, soap

I have a soap function in which I need to use the argument 'pass'.
"Pass" in Python is a statement so it can't be used.

How can I bypass this? I'm using Zeep for Soap.

```
relatie=4841
email="email"
password="password"
exportData=3600
administration={'admCode': 'BBOY', 'admMap': None}
formaat=1

result = client.service.Export(relatie=relatie, email=email, pass=password, exportData=exportData, administration=administration, formaat=format)
```

Comment: `client.service.Export(..., **{"pass" : password})` should do the trick.

Comment: @Torxed make it an answer so this question can be marked as answered.

Comment: @AlexHall Good idea, heh. I've had a bad habbit of answering questions in comments and not thinking of the question actually being marked as solved. Thanks for reminding me! :)

Comment: OP, to learn more, Google "python kwargs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this thing called unpacking explicit dictionaries.
It basically means you can unpack a dictionary while sending it to a function and every key will act as a parameter and the value of that dictionary item will become the value for said parameter.

```
relatie=4841
email="email"
password="password"
exportData=3600
administration={'admCode': 'BBOY', 'admMap': None}
formaat=1

result = client.service.Export(relatie=relatie, email=email,  exportData=exportData, administration=administration, formaat=format, **{"pass" : password})
```

This should give the function what it wants. To learn more about this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769478/929999) is a great answer explaining it with some examples.

Exploring this further, a cleaner way would be to not mix the two techniques, but instead use the unpacking of a dictionary all together on this call.

```
parameters = {'relatie' : 4841,
              'email' : 'email',
              'exportData' : 3600,
              'administration' : {'admCode': 'BBOY', 'admMap': None},
              'formaat' : 1, # Not sure if format is misspelled
              "pass" : "password"}

result = client.service.Export(**parameters)
```

This way, you don't need to create individual variables for all your options, and then add them to the dictionary/pass it individually. But the dictionary itself can act as a placeholder for all your values, and then you just unpack/expload it into the `Export()` function and assuming nothing is misspelled or not expected, this should do the trick.